# Serialize/deserialize without external library in c#

Tags: c#, json, visual-studio

How do i serialize/de serialize JSON data in c# without using any library or nugget package

i tried this
it allways shows me error!

````
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Deserialize an from json string
    /// </summary>
    public static T Deserialize<T>(string body)
    {
        using (var stream = new MemoryStream())
        using (var writer = new StreamWriter(stream))
        {
            writer.Write(body);
            writer.Flush();
            stream.Position = 0;
            return (T)new DataContractJsonSerializer(typeof(T)).ReadObject(stream);
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Serialize an object to json
    /// </summary>
    public static string Serialize<T>(T item)
    {
        using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
        {
            new DataContractJsonSerializer(typeof(T)).WriteObject(ms, item);
            return Encoding.Default.GetString(ms.ToArray());
        }
    }
}```
````

Comment: What error? Please clarify it. First of all for ```DataContractJsonSerializer``` all models need to be marked with ```DataContractAttribute``` ( https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wcf/feature-details/how-to-serialize-and-deserialize-json-data ) - check if you do it. Second, instead ```Encoding.Default``` better to use concrete encoding (like ```Encoding.UTF8```). And last, how about ```System.Text.Json``` https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.json?view=net-6.0 ? It's a part of .NET (not a third part library).

Answer (score 2):

**System.Text.Json** as a library from Microsoft and **Newtonsoft.Json**, an external serializer friend.

Answer (score 0):

Dotnet has a library for your request [Source page](https://learn.microsoft.com/tr-tr/dotnet/standard/serialization/system-text-json-how-to?pivots=dotnet-6-0)

```
string jsonString = JsonSerializer.Serialize(weatherForecast);

var weatherForecast = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<WeatherForecast>(jsonString);
```